# Default value to multi-line item

Tags: salesforce-id, opportunity-lineitem

I am trying to get a default value to multi-line item in product, (go to opp > Products (Standard Price Book) > add Product > select some product name and click select) This window will get open.
[image]

is it possible to make the quantity default value to 1.

Comment: What do you mean with "multi-line item"?

Comment: Your question (and the tags selection!) is very confusing. You mean textarea fields? You can, as long as they're custom fields. Multiselect picklists? In that case only 1 value can be default...

Comment: I have edited my question, this might help you people to understand.

Comment: It's more the multilineedit oli page I reckon...

Answer (score 1):

You can default the unit price but not the quantity when adding a product to a PriceBook.

The PriceBookEntry is what you're referencing when adding products to an Opportunity, so you will need to type in the Quantities.
([PricebookEntry](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_pricebookentry.htm) has no field for Quantity)

Answer (score 0):

You can request that Quantity default to "1" by logging a Case with salesforce. Then, you could even remove the Quantity field from the layout completely. I've seen this done many times.